# SQLite SELECT from VB.Net application (Win32)

Tags: vb.net, sqlite

I am trying to get a result from SQL database and keep it as a variable. But with my code (see below) it returns 0 (zero). Any ideas of what am i doing wrong?

Thanks

```
Function getName(name As String)
    Dim SQLconnect As New SQLite.SQLiteConnection()
    Dim SQLcommand As SQLite.SQLiteCommand

    SQLconnect.ConnectionString = "Data Source=C:\tools\names.sqlite;"
    SQLconnect.Open()

    SQLcommand = SQLconnect.CreateCommand

    SQLcommand.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM names WHERE name = " & name & " LIMIT 1;"
    Dim sqlResponse As String = SQLcommand.ExecuteNonQuery()


End Function
```

EDIT: I am using "return sqlResponse" for return

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing, the sql should be(I think):

```
SQLcommand.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM names WHERE name = '" & name & "' LIMIT 1;"
```

I am not sure how text is represented in SQLite but you need some kind of delimiter like a single quote in SQL Server.

Second thing, use paramterized query to stop yourself from being hijacked by SQL Injections

Third, a SELECT uses a ExecuteReader, and in case where you want only one item, try ExecuteScalar. ExecuteNonQuery is for insert, update delete.

Comment: It worked with ExecuteScalar! Many many thanks! This is the correct answer!

Answer (score 1):

Execute`NonQuery` does not return a value so therefore it will always be `0`. You need to use

```
Dim sqlResponse As String = SQLcommand.ExecuteScalar()
```